# Notification to commit/push upon code change

Tags: git, github, notifications, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a bunch of team-mates, who change their code in their respective code editiors but often forget to commit and push through `Git`. Is there anyway to send notifications to them upon code change, inorder to notify them to commit and push via Git.

We use `Gitlab` and `Sourcetree` as GUI client for Git.

Comment: But we dont push via code editors. We use GUI client `Sourcetree`. All people are newbees. So inorder to simplify the process, we kept same client for everyone instead of confusing them with individual code editor options. That makes, integration plugins in code editors is not a solution.

Comment: So have to reaserch about plugins for individual code edititors. We use, `keil`, `Delphi RAD studio`(various versions) , `Atom` etc

Answer (score 2):

IDE have status bar showing what is not pushed... but that can be ignored.

Your idea was suggested for IntelliJ IDEA: [IDEA-151612](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151612), but is still pending.

> Message about outgoing not pushed commits
>
> It would be a great feature if I could have an option in settings to enable warning when I close IDE, if I have some not pushed code in my current local GIT repo.

Beside IDE plugins, since SourceTree alone would not offer this feature, you would need to implement a process running at regular interval, "nagging" the user for committing and pushing(!).

---

The alternative is to code in a **web-IDE** provided by the Git repository hosting server itself.

GitLab just proposed such an IDE in "[Meet the **GitLab Web IDE**](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/06/15/introducing-gitlab-s-integrated-development-environment/)":

> The original idea came from staff developer [**Jacob Schatz**](https://about.gitlab.com/team/#jakecodes), who observed how non-developers were having a hard time editing multiple files and getting those changes committed.
>
> It took some time, but it was clear that we were aiming for a real integrated development experience, accessible for everyone right within the GitLab UI, without anything to install. The idea grew from the "Repo editor" into that of the "Web IDE."

See [issue 44846](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/44846): it includes a "Commit mode", and a "Commit overview at bottom sidebar"

[image: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/uploads/0c78c2c19b30af8d49370f0f65c0778a/view1_copy_15.png]

Comment: Any idea about What plugins must be used for Delphi and Keil for notifying?

Comment: @RajanaDeepak Delphi as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi_(IDE)? Keil as in http://www2.keil.com/mdk5/uvision/? No, I don't know. You can implement that nagging process as an external tasks, scheduled at the OS level (task on Windows, cron job on Linux) to check the local repo status.

Comment: @RajanaDeepak I have edited the answer to add an alternative.

Comment: It is fine but we dont use CI/CD but depend on IDE compiler. While makes, sadly, this `web IDE` is not so useful for us.

Comment: Sure, I was simply mentioning that alternative for other readers